# Style post archive blog preview based on category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page showing your typical series of small post teasers - images, excerpt etc which advertise properties for lease.

I would like to have the ability to add a 'new' or 'featured' icon based on its corresponding 'new' or 'featured' category or tag - either will do.

I have added these categories but they do not appear in the code when output and so I cannot target them.

How would I be able to perform the action:

If a post thumbnail has category of 'new' add the class 'new' so I can then target and style - repeating for each category.

I found this which I think is similar but does not work

There will be multiple categories displaying on the archive page, but I want to style only the previews that have a certain category - I do not want to style the individual post page.

Unfortunately my php skills are limited

Thanks

```
$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category('new', $post->ID) ) { ?>
    <body <?php body_class('new'); ?>> 
<?php
} 

elseif ( in_category('featured', $post->ID) ) { ?>
    <body <?php body_class('featured'); ?>> 
<?php
} 

else { ?>
    <body <?php body_class('class-name-generic'); ?>>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go `get_the_category($post->ID);` will return the array of categories of that post you need to loop through the array

```
$category_detail=get_the_category('4');//$post->ID
foreach($category_detail as $cd){
echo $cd->cat_name;
}
```

Comment: Hi there

Thank you for your time. So I have placed that exactly as is, in my functions php but it does not appear to work.

Comment: Okay,give me your code so we will check and fix that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean ?

I placed the code you provided above starting from $category in my functions php but it does not work

Thanks again

Comment: Please provide your function so I will understand and fix it.